# Relabeling and matching variables (in MultiplicationTable)

Tags: variable, algebra, group-theory

Suppose we have a set of data given here as the multiplication table of 8 elements labeled {1,2,3,4,9,10,11,12}:
$$
\begin{array}{cccccccc}
 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
 2 & 1 & 4 & 3 & 12 & 11 & 10 & 9 \\
 3 & 4 & 1 & 2 & 10 & 9 & 12 & 11 \\
 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 11 & 12 & 9 & 10 \\
 9 & 12 & 11 & 10 & 1 & 4 & 3 & 2 \\
 10 & 11 & 12 & 9 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 4 \\
 11 & 10 & 9 & 12 & 4 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
 12 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 1 \\
\end{array}
$$
and it seems that it matches to the MultiplicationTable {"DihedralGroup", 4}

```
FiniteGroupData[{"DihedralGroup", 4}, "MultiplicationTable"] // Grid
```

which  outputs:

$$\begin{array}{cccccccc}
 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
 2 & 3 & 4 & 1 & 8 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
 3 & 4 & 1 & 2 & 7 & 8 & 5 & 6 \\
 4 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 5 \\
 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
 6 & 7 & 8 & 5 & 4 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
 7 & 8 & 5 & 6 & 3 & 4 & 1 & 2 \\
 8 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 1 \\
\end{array}
$$

> question: Is there some smart algorithm to relabels the variables and check the MultiplicationTable match or does not match?

We can use these as a Test toy model example. Thanks the expert's reply!

Comment: i.e., you want to check if two groups (represented by their multiplication tables) are isomorphic?

Comment: Yes- thank you Sir, simply speaking - me needs help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example

```
A = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 10, 11, 12}, {2, 1, 4, 3, 12, 11, 10, 9}, 
    {3, 4, 1, 2, 10, 9, 12, 11}, {4, 3, 2, 1, 11, 12, 9, 10}, 
    {9, 12, 11, 10, 1, 4, 3, 2}, {10, 11, 12, 9, 3, 2, 1, 4}, 
    {11, 10, 9, 12, 4, 1, 2, 3}, {12, 9, 10, 11, 2, 3, 4, 1}};
B = FiniteGroupData[{"DihedralGroup", 4}, "MultiplicationTable"];
```

Direct search of *would be matrices be the same up to renaming* (using all the permutations):

```
n = Length@A;
perms = Permutations[Range@n];
FlB = Flatten[B];
subst[list_] := Table[A[[list[[i]], list[[j]]]], {i, n}, {j, n}]
lnght[A$_] := Length@Union@Transpose@{Flatten[A$], FlB}
Min[lnght[subst[#]] & /@ perms]
```

gives $8$, so the two groups are isomorphic indeed.

This produces the first isomorphism encountered:

```
For[k = 1, k <= Length@perms, k++,
 If[lnght[subst[perms[[k]]]] == n, 
  Print[Union@Transpose@{Flatten[subst@perms[[k]]], FlB}]; Break[]]]
```

And this gives all isomorphisms:

```
For[k = 1, k <= Length@perms, k++,
 If[lnght[subst[perms[[k]]]] == n, 
  Print[Union@Transpose@{Flatten[subst@perms[[k]]], FlB}]; Break[]]]
```

Comment: @ Andrew, +1, thanks, what will be the output and minimal code in this toy model example? Thank you! -

Comment: @wonderich the previous solution didn't take into account the possibility of another elements order. Unfortunately the new answer is just checking all the variants.

Comment: @ Andrew, however, do you have a way to suggest the map between two tables, like {1 to 1}, {2 to ...}, {3 to ...}? From a more systematic output?

Comment: @ Andrew, this will be one example that big data makes the error message: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/170990/

Comment: @wonderich for your first question I've edited the answer. As for the second idk an efficient algorithm.