# Relabeling/matching variables of big data (in MultiplicationTable)

Tags: algebra, group-theory

Let A and B be two sets of tables (from multiplication tables of a group, 24 by 24 as rows by columns), 
how can we effectively (and possibly also efficiently) find a way to map between them, if two groups are indeed isomorphism, under the relabelling of group elements?

Based on the strategy given in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/170777/)

```
A={{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 
  20, 21, 22, 23, 24}, {2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5, 8, 7, 12, 11, 10, 9, 14, 13,
   16, 15, 18, 17, 20, 19, 22, 21, 24, 23}, {3, 4, 1, 2, 7, 8, 5, 6, 
  10, 9, 12, 11, 16, 15, 14, 13, 20, 19, 18, 17, 24, 23, 22, 21}, {4, 
  3, 2, 1, 8, 7, 6, 5, 11, 12, 9, 10, 15, 16, 13, 14, 19, 20, 17, 18, 
  23, 24, 21, 22}, {5, 7, 6, 8, 1, 3, 2, 4, 18, 17, 20, 19, 24, 21, 
  22, 23, 10, 9, 12, 11, 14, 15, 16, 13}, {6, 8, 5, 7, 2, 4, 1, 3, 17,
   18, 19, 20, 23, 22, 21, 24, 11, 12, 9, 10, 13, 16, 15, 14}, {7, 5, 
  8, 6, 3, 1, 4, 2, 19, 20, 17, 18, 21, 24, 23, 22, 9, 10, 11, 12, 15,
   14, 13, 16}, {8, 6, 7, 5, 4, 2, 3, 1, 20, 19, 18, 17, 22, 23, 24, 
  21, 12, 11, 10, 9, 16, 13, 14, 15}, {9, 12, 11, 10, 23, 24, 21, 22, 
  1, 4, 3, 2, 20, 19, 17, 18, 15, 16, 14, 13, 7, 8, 5, 6}, {10, 11, 
  12, 9, 22, 21, 24, 23, 3, 2, 1, 4, 17, 18, 20, 19, 14, 13, 15, 16, 
  5, 6, 7, 8}, {11, 10, 9, 12, 21, 22, 23, 24, 4, 1, 2, 3, 18, 17, 19,
   20, 13, 14, 16, 15, 6, 5, 8, 7}, {12, 9, 10, 11, 24, 23, 22, 21, 2,
   3, 4, 1, 19, 20, 18, 17, 16, 15, 13, 14, 8, 7, 6, 5}, {13, 15, 16, 
  14, 19, 17, 18, 20, 22, 23, 21, 24, 1, 4, 2, 3, 6, 7, 5, 8, 11, 9, 
  10, 12}, {14, 16, 15, 13, 20, 18, 17, 19, 21, 24, 22, 23, 2, 3, 1, 
  4, 5, 8, 6, 7, 10, 12, 11, 9}, {15, 13, 14, 16, 17, 19, 20, 18, 24, 
  21, 23, 22, 4, 1, 3, 2, 7, 6, 8, 5, 9, 11, 12, 10}, {16, 14, 13, 15,
   18, 20, 19, 17, 23, 22, 24, 21, 3, 2, 4, 1, 8, 5, 7, 6, 12, 10, 9, 
  11}, {17, 20, 19, 18, 15, 14, 13, 16, 6, 7, 5, 8, 10, 9, 11, 12, 21,
   24, 22, 23, 1, 3, 2, 4}, {18, 19, 20, 17, 16, 13, 14, 15, 5, 8, 6, 
  7, 11, 12, 10, 9, 22, 23, 21, 24, 2, 4, 1, 3}, {19, 18, 17, 20, 13, 
  16, 15, 14, 7, 6, 8, 5, 12, 11, 9, 10, 23, 22, 24, 21, 4, 2, 3, 
  1}, {20, 17, 18, 19, 14, 15, 16, 13, 8, 5, 7, 6, 9, 10, 12, 11, 24, 
  21, 23, 22, 3, 1, 4, 2}, {21, 23, 22, 24, 11, 9, 10, 12, 14, 13, 15,
   16, 7, 6, 5, 8, 1, 4, 3, 2, 17, 19, 20, 18}, {22, 24, 21, 23, 10, 
  12, 11, 9, 13, 14, 16, 15, 8, 5, 6, 7, 2, 3, 4, 1, 18, 20, 19, 
  17}, {23, 21, 24, 22, 9, 11, 12, 10, 16, 15, 13, 14, 6, 7, 8, 5, 4, 
  1, 2, 3, 19, 17, 18, 20}, {24, 22, 23, 21, 12, 10, 9, 11, 15, 16, 
  14, 13, 5, 8, 7, 6, 3, 2, 1, 4, 20, 18, 17, 19}};
B = FiniteGroupData[{"SymmetricGroup", 4}, "MultiplicationTable"];
n = Length@A;
perms = Permutations[Range@n];
FlB = Flatten[B];
subst[list_] := Table[A[[list[[i]], list[[j]]]], {i, n}, {j, n}]
lnght[A$_] := Length@Union@Transpose@{Flatten[A$], FlB}
Min[lnght[subst[#]] & /@ perms]
```

There is a limitation of the Permutations[Range[24]], perhaps the system size is too large? This results in an output:
[image]

> question 1. Can we still find a way out to do Permutations[Range[24]]? Or is there a more efficient way to find the group isomorphism?
>
> question 2. How do we suggest a map between the two tables, say from {1 to 1}, {2 to ...}, {3 to ...}? If the map can be found?

Note: This will be the table look like in Grid:
[image]

Comment: p.s. There is so far not yet a complete answer.

Answer (score 5):

For a start, the order of an element is invariant under group isomorphisms. This boils the number of permutations to test from $24! = 620448401733239439360000$  down to $6! \, 8! \, 9! = 10534551552000$. The order of the $i$th element can actually determined from row `A[[i]]` alone. The following function `getGroupElementOrder` does that for you:

```
getGroupElementOrders = Compile[{{a, _Integer, 1}, {g, _Integer}},
   Block[{i = g, c = 1},
    While[i != 1, c++; i = Compile`GetElement[a, i]];
    c
    ],
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True
   ];

n = Length[A];
ordersA = getGroupElementOrders[A, Range[n]];
ordersB = getGroupElementOrders[B, Range[n]];
elementsInAOfOrder = GroupBy[Transpose[{ordersA, Range[n]}], First -> Last]
elementsInBOfOrder = GroupBy[Transpose[{ordersB, Range[n]}], First -> Last]
```

> <|1 -> {1}, 2 -> {2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 12, 13, 16}, 
>    4 -> {6, 7, 10, 11, 14, 15}, 3 -> {17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24}|>
>
> <|1 -> {1}, 2 -> {2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 15, 17, 22, 24}, 
>    3 -> {4, 5, 9, 12, 13, 16, 20, 21}, 4 -> {10, 11, 14, 18, 19, 23}|>

No, you are "only" left to match members of `elementsInAOfOrder[k]` with `elementsInBOfOrder[k]` for $k = 2,3,4$ ...

Comment: @ Henrik Schumacher, thanks, +1, indeed I was thinking about the diagonal, too. However, there are still many choices, how can we pin down precisely to a single mapping? [there is at least a single mapping if it exists, and one can find perhaps 4!=24 distinct mapping in total. If we restrict 1 maps to 1, then there should be at most 3!=6 mappings.]

Comment: Oh, pinning down to one unique isomorphism is in general impossible. There are groups with nontrivial automorphisms, you know...

Comment: yes, just give any one is fine, as said, there are 24 possible mappings. Does your algorithm give any map for checking isomorphism? (in order to accept as an answer)

Comment: That's not a complete answer at all, sorry.